# Twitter bootstrap and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to put the `bootstrap` source files in my `rails` project but I am not seeing an `"assets"` folder in my app folder. Are the Image, `Javascript`, and `CSS` folders in "public" the same thing? If not then where do I put the source files? I am using ruby version 1.9.2-p290, rails version 3.0.19, and bootstrap version 2.3.2. Not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: `I am using rails 1.9.2-p290` what is it it should be ruby I think

Comment: `1.9.2-p290` is a version of Ruby. What version of Rails and Bootstrap are you trying to use? Regardless look into `bootstrap-sass` gem.

Comment: 1.9.2-p290 is a ruby version. what's your rails version?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a bootstrap gem like [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) instead?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this project: [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails)

It is an easy way to set up bootstrap in your Ruby on Rails project.